# How to disallow a post method from Get method in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am just learning about WebAPIs and curious if we can reuse the Post method inside get method or it just violates the coding standards. How can we test if this violation is already done by someone?

```
 // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        var value= vc.Values.Where(v => v.Id == id).Select(v => v.Value1).SingleOrDefault(); 
        if (value==null) Post("New Value",id);
        return vc.Values.Where(v => v.Id == id).Select(v => v.Value1).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value, int id = 0)
    {
        vc.Values.Add(new Value { Id=id,Value1 = value });
        vc.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't. `Get` should retrieve data, not create it if it's missing.

Comment: ok Thanks. How can we write test cases for this type of error or something which can scan the code/project for this type of errors.

Comment: Yes, you can call your web service like a method and it works but this breaks some rules like SOLID.

Comment: @FurkanÖztürk Do you know any code quality tools which can help in detecting it?

Comment: You can take a look at **SonarQube** @DeepakMishra

Comment: Usually, when a get method doesn't find a value, it should return an 404. Check out [HTTP response codes list on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors)

Comment: @FurkanÖztürk I have installed Resharper, even it is not able to detect it. Could you please give an example with SonarQube on how to detect it?

Comment: @DeepakMishra: That is different question than the actual one. Please modify the actual question or create a new one.

Comment: @Div modified the question

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 questions, not one.

Reusing code like this is a recipe for disaster. 
You can keep your endpoints very slim by moving the code into a library for example. Then you can simply call these new methods from the endpoints and this takes care of the code reuse part.

In terms of how you detect such issues, well, I wouldn't expect a tool to do it for you. You need a mature SDLC, you need code reviews and analysis on what you have already.

Comment: +1, good knowledge but things like "recipe for disaster" could be avoided as this is not a production ready code, the intent is just to make the system aware that something is wrong if something is wrong. I was looking for something which detects and validate these things in WebAPI may be a unit test.